# Change the URL through PHP

Tags: php, url

I want to change the URL through PHP.

Something like `window.location.href = "http://www.something.com"` in JavaScript.

I want the same thing but in PHP. How can I do it?

Comment: The PHP Network Function `header`, can also send `$http_response_code`  [php.net/manual](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: This is not "changing the URL" but redirecting.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the **[`header`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)** function for that:

```
header("Location: http://www.something.com/");
exit;
```

Note that such call must be followed by `exit` as to stop any other code from execution.

In case it errors out with "Headers already sent", refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the header() command:

```
<?php
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Make sure there is **nothing** above the line outputted, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: Or you can also call ob_start() to turn on output buffering.

Comment: @futureelite7 which is always a bad practice. You should fix the wrong structure of your application instead of miking it output a ton of HTML but then all of sudden ask to take it all back.

Answer (score -1):

> You could use **ob_start** along with the **header** *function* in
>   order to prevent redirection errors like so:

```
<?php
   ob_start(); // Starts Output Buffering 
   header(/*Your redirection's location*/); // Redirects user to given location.
?>
```

Comment: You would need `header('Location: /*Your redirection's location*/');`