# How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

When running my script, I am getting several errors like this:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (**output started at /some/file.php:12**) in **/some/file.php** on **line 23**

The lines mentioned in the error messages contain [`header()`](http://php.net/header) and [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie) calls.

What could be the reason for this? And how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure no text is outputted (`ob_start` and `ob_end_clean() ` may prove useful here). You could then set a cookie or session equal to `ob_get_contents()` and then use `ob_end_clean()` to clear the buffer.

Comment: ~~~~~~~~~~ Your file ENCODING should not be `UTF-8`, but `UTF-8 (Without BOM)`~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 3327, accepted):

### No output before sending headers!

Functions that send/modify HTTP headers must be invoked ***before any output is made***.
<kbd>[**summary ⇊**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028979/345031)</kbd>
Otherwise the call fails:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (output started at *script:line*)

Some functions modifying the HTTP header are:

- [`header`](http://php.net/header) / [`header_remove`](http://php.net/header_remove)
- [`session_start`](http://php.net/session_start) / [`session_regenerate_id`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id)
- [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) / [`setrawcookie`](http://php.net/setrawcookie)

Output can be:

- *Unintentional:*

  - Whitespace before `<?php` or after `?>`
  - The [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) specifically
  - Previous error messages or notices

- *Intentional:*

  - `print`, `echo` and other functions producing output
  - Raw `<html>` sections prior `<?php` code.

### Why does it happen?

To understand why headers must be sent before output it's necessary
to look at a typical [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)
response. PHP scripts mainly generate HTML content, but also pass a
set of HTTP/CGI headers to the webserver:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Powered-By: PHP/5.3.7
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><head><title>PHP page output page</title></head>
<body><h1>Content</h1> <p>Some more output follows...</p>
and <a href="/"> <img src=internal-icon-delayed> </a>
```

The page/output always *follows* the headers. PHP has to pass the
headers to the webserver first. It can only do that once.
After the double linebreak it can nevermore amend them.

When PHP receives the first output (`print`, `echo`, `<html>`) it will
*flush* all collected headers. Afterward it can send all the output
it wants. But sending further HTTP headers is impossible then.

### How can you find out where the premature output occurred?

The `header()` warning contains all relevant information to
locate the problem cause:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> ***(output started at*** /www/usr2345/htdocs/**auth.php:52**) in
> /www/usr2345/htdocs/index.php on line 100

Here "line 100" refers to the script where the `header()` *invocation* failed.

The "*output started at*" note within the parenthesis is more significant.
It denominates the source of previous output. In this example, it's `auth.php`
and **line `52`**. That's where you had to look for premature output.

*Typical causes:*

1. #### Print, echo

   Intentional output from `print` and `echo` statements will terminate the opportunity to send HTTP headers. The application flow must be restructured to avoid that. Use [functions](http://php.net/function)
   and templating schemes. Ensure `header()` calls occur *before* messages
   are written out.

   Functions that produce output include

   - `print`, `echo`, `printf`, `vprintf`
   - `trigger_error`, `ob_flush`, `ob_end_flush`, `var_dump`, `print_r`
   - `readfile`, `passthru`, `flush`, `imagepng`, `imagejpeg`

   among others and user-defined functions.
2. #### Raw HTML areas

   Unparsed HTML sections in a `.php` file are direct output as well.
   Script conditions that will trigger a `header()` call must be noted
   before *any* raw `<html>` blocks.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <?php
       // Too late for headers already.
   ```

   Use a templating scheme to separate processing from output logic.

   - Place form processing code atop scripts.
   - Use temporary string variables to defer messages.
   - The actual output logic and intermixed HTML output should follow last.
3. #### Whitespace before `<?php` for "script.php **line 1**" warnings

   If the warning refers to output inline **`1`**, then it's mostly
   leading **whitespace**, text or HTML before the opening `<?php` token.

   ```
    <?php
   # There's a SINGLE space/newline before <? - Which already seals it.
   ```

   Similarly it can occur for appended scripts or script sections:

   ```
   ?>

   <?php
   ```

   PHP actually eats up a *single* linebreak after close tags. But it won't
   compensate multiple newlines or tabs or spaces shifted into such gaps.
4. #### UTF-8 BOM

   Linebreaks and spaces alone can be a problem. But there are also "invisible"
   character sequences that can cause this. Most famously the
   [**UTF-8 BOM** (Byte-Order-Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
   which isn't displayed by most text editors. It's the byte sequence `EF BB BF`, which is optional and redundant for UTF-8 encoded documents. PHP however has to treat it as raw output. It may show up as the characters `ï»¿` in the output (if the client interprets the document as Latin-1) or similar "garbage".

   In particular graphical editors and Java-based IDEs are oblivious to its
   presence. They don't visualize it (obliged by the Unicode standard).
   Most programmer and console editors however do:

   [image: joes editor showing UTF-8 BOM placeholder, and MC editor a dot]

   There it's easy to recognize the problem early on. Other editors may identify
   its presence in a file/settings menu (Notepad++ on Windows can identify and
   [remedy the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589358/fix-utf8-bom)),
   Another option to inspect the BOMs presence is resorting to an **hexeditor**.
   On *nix systems [`hexdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump) is usually available,
   if not a graphical variant which simplifies auditing these and other issues:

   [image: beav hexeditor showing utf-8 bom]

   An easy fix is to set the text editor to save files as "UTF-8 (no BOM)"
   or similar to such nomenclature. Often newcomers otherwise resort to creating new files and just copy&pasting the previous code back in.

   #### Correction utilities [image]

   There are also automated tools to examine and rewrite text files
   ([`sed`/`awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark) or `recode`).
   For PHP specifically there's the [`phptags` tag tidier](http://freshcode.club/projects/phptags).
   It rewrites close and open tags into long and short forms, but also easily
   fixes leading and trailing whitespace, Unicode and UTF-x BOM issues:

   ```
   phptags  --whitespace  *.php
   ```

   It's safe to use on a whole include or project directory.
5. #### Whitespace after `?>`

   If the error source is mentioned as behind the
   [closing `?>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/php-closing-tag)
   then this is where some whitespace or the raw text got written out.
   The PHP end marker does not terminate script execution at this point. Any text/space characters after it will be written out as page content
   still.

   It's commonly advised, in particular to newcomers, that trailing `?>` PHP
   close tags should be omitted. This *eschews* a small portion of these cases.
   (Quite commonly `include()d` scripts are the culprit.)
6. #### Error source mentioned as "Unknown on line 0"

   It's typically a PHP extension or php.ini setting if no error source
   is concretized.

   - It's occasionally the `gzip` stream encoding setting
     [or the `ob_gzhandler`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622192/php-warning-headers-already-sent-in-unknown).
   - But it could also be any doubly loaded `extension=` module
     generating an implicit PHP startup/warning message.
7. #### Preceding error messages

   If another PHP statement or expression causes a warning message or
   notice being printed out, that also counts as premature output.

   In this case you need to eschew the error,
   delay the statement execution, or suppress the message with e.g.
   [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) or [`@()`](http://php.net/@) -
   when either doesn't obstruct debugging later on.

### No error message

If you have `error_reporting` or `display_errors` disabled per `php.ini`,
then no warning will show up. But ignoring errors won't make the problem go
away. Headers still can't be sent after premature output.

So when `header("Location: ...")` redirects silently fail it's very
advisable to probe for warnings. Reenable them with two simple commands
atop the invocation script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Or `set_error_handler("var_dump");` if all else fails.

Speaking of redirect headers, you should often use an idiom like
this for final code paths:

```
exit(header("Location: /finished.html"));
```

Preferably even a utility function, which prints a user message
in case of `header()` failures.

### Output buffering as a workaround

PHPs [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php)
is a workaround to alleviate this issue. It often works reliably, but shouldn't
substitute for proper application structuring and separating output from control
logic. Its actual purpose is minimizing chunked transfers to the webserver.

1. The [`output_buffering=`](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php)
   setting nevertheless can help.
   Configure it in the [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)
   or via [.htaccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)
   or even [.user.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) on
   modern FPM/FastCGI setups.
   Enabling it will allow PHP to buffer output instead of passing it to the webserver instantly. PHP thus can aggregate HTTP headers.
2. It can likewise be engaged with a call to [`ob_start();`](http://php.net/ob_start)
   atop the invocation script. Which however is less reliable for multiple reasons:

   - Even if `<?php ob_start(); ?>` starts the first script, whitespace or a
     BOM might get shuffled before, [rendering it ineffective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168956/php-header-problem-even-i-use-ob-start-and-ob-end-flush).
   - It can conceal whitespace for HTML output. But as soon as the application logic attempts to send binary content (a generated image for example),
     the buffered extraneous output becomes a problem. (Necessitating `ob_clean()`
     as a further workaround.)
   - The buffer is limited in size, and can easily overrun when left to defaults.
     And that's not a rare occurrence either, [difficult to track down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643837/php-headers-already-sent-error-depending-on-output-length)
     when it happens.

Both approaches therefore may become unreliable - in particular when switching between
development setups and/or production servers. This is why output buffering is
widely considered just a crutch / strictly a workaround.

See also the [basic usage example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.examples.basic.php)
in the manual, and for more pros and cons:

- [What is output buffering in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering)
- [Why use output buffering in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148114/why-use-output-buffering-in-php)
- [Is using output buffering considered a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731375/is-using-output-buffering-considered-a-bad-practice)
- [Use case for output buffering as the correct solution to "headers already sent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919569/use-case-for-output-buffering-as-the-correct-solution-to-headers-already-sent)

#### But it worked on the other server!?

If you didn't get the headers warning before, then the [output buffering
php.ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php)
has changed. It's likely unconfigured on the current/new server.

### Checking with `headers_sent()`

You can always use [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/headers_sent) to probe if
it's still possible to... send headers. Which is useful to conditionally print
info or apply other fallback logic.

```
if (headers_sent()) {
    die("Redirect failed. Please click on this link: <a href=...>");
}
else{
    exit(header("Location: /user.php"));
}
```

Useful fallback workarounds are:

- #### HTML `<meta>` tag

  If your application is structurally hard to fix, then an easy (but
  somewhat unprofessional) way to allow redirects is injecting a HTML
  `<meta>` tag. A redirect can be achieved with:

  ```
   <meta http-equiv="Location" content="http://example.com/">
  ```

  Or with a short delay:

  ```
   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; url=../target.html">
  ```

  This leads to non-valid HTML when utilized past the `<head>` section.
  Most browsers still accept it.
- #### JavaScript redirect

  As alternative a [JavaScript redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)
  can be used for page redirects:

  ```
   <script> location.replace("target.html"); </script>
  ```

  While this is often more HTML compliant than the `<meta>` workaround,
  it incurs a reliance on JavaScript-capable clients.

Both approaches however make acceptable fallbacks when genuine HTTP header()
calls fail. Ideally you'd always combine this with a user-friendly message and
clickable link as last resort. (Which for instance is what the [http_redirect()](https://php.uz/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php)
PECL extension does.)

### Why `setcookie()` and `session_start()` are also affected

Both `setcookie()` and `session_start()` need to send a `Set-Cookie:` HTTP header.
The same conditions therefore apply, and similar error messages will be generated
for premature output situations.

(Of course, they're furthermore affected by disabled cookies in the browser
or even proxy issues. The session functionality obviously also depends on free
disk space and other php.ini settings, etc.)

### Further links

- Google provides a [lengthy list of similar discussions](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+headers+already+sent).
- And of course [many specific cases](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+headers+already+sent) have been covered on Stack Overflow as well.
- The WordPress FAQ explains [How do I solve the Headers already sent warning problem?](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F) in a generic manner.
- Adobe Community: [PHP development: why redirects don't work (headers already sent)](http://kb2.adobe.com/community/publishing/505/cpsid_50572.html)
- Nucleus FAQ: [What does "page headers already sent" mean?](http://faq.nucleuscms.org/item/79)
- One of the more thorough explanations is [HTTP Headers and the PHP header() Function - A tutorial by NicholasSolutions](http://web.archive.org/web/20080430141149/http://www.expertsrt.com/tutorials/Matt/HTTP_headers.html) (Internet Archive link).
  It covers HTTP in detail and gives a few guidelines for rewriting scripts.

Comment: Also regular notepad.exe is tricky. I use NetBeans normally that doesn't add BOM, even if file is encoded so. Editing a file later in notepad messes things up, especially towards IIS as webserver. It seems as apache discards the (unitentionally added) BOM.

Comment: Removing the closing `?>` from the end of a php files is usually a good practice which helps minimizing these errors as well. Unwanted whitespace will not occur at the end of files, and you will still be able to add headers to the response later. It is also handy if you use output buffering, and would not like to see added unwanted whitespace at the end of the parts generated by the included files.

Comment: Strange thing, I moved my file from cPanel Linux Hosting to VPS. Before it was working properly but here it showed this error.(I had some html code before header). Why?

Comment: @Purushotamrawat Did you read the part about "**But it worked on the other server!?**"

Comment: @mario but I didn't change the Output Buffering

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor because it waits before sending anything to the client until the complete output is rendered/buffered server-side. Without output buffering, the server starts sending out the data as it gets generated (streaming), in which case it needs to send out headers first which cannot be manipulated later on.

Comment: and sometimes its just about php version! its so difficult to edit all complicated codes and its better to change your server php version to most compatible with your cods

Comment: When the page loads I already have a Content-Type: header loaded  and sent. What setting made this happen?

Comment: @PeterSMcIntyre The UTF8 BOM presumably (fix that) / no output buffering enabled (don't rely on that).

Comment: I just want to mention that using `curl` and not setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `TRUE` can also produce output and therefore trigger 'headers already sent'-error

Comment: Thanks for adding the unintentional causes in the beginning. I had one, tiny, little space before a `<?php` tag in one of my included files.

Comment: If you really need to display content before forwarding. You can use replace in JavaScript: window.location.replace("http://newUrl.com");. You can set up a recursive JS function with setTimeout()  that looks for information on the page that signals that it's time to forward and then calls replace.

Comment: For the "But it worked on the other server!?" part -- it was my case, in case of running your own local server, try to edit the php.ini file and set output_buffering to output_buffering=4096. IF THIS STILL DOES NOT WORK - try to increase it. That was my problem. I had to increase buffer to 64kb because some pages were just that big. Oh and also do not forget to restart server, just in case.

Comment: If you are using UltraEdit, Save-As  (Select Encoding option bottom right) UTF-8 No boM   (this fixed it for me)

Comment: Whitespace before <?php for "script.php line 1" warnings worked for me. Thanks for this awesome explanation

Comment: Just one detail missed you may want to add. `$file = $line = null; headers_sent($file, $line); die("$file:$line");` will tell you exactly what sent the headers, if the error message omits that info. Not sure why, but sometimes that seems to be the case.

Comment: What an answer! I can't believe that I had to spend several hours because of one empty line at the top. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Regarding case 6, unknown source for the error may be related to requests aborted by the browser (look for HTTP status 499 in the access log, although it may not appear in all cases). `ignore_user_abort=On` may fix/workaround the "Headers already sent" notices in such cases, it worked for me at least.

Answer (score 218):

This error message gets triggered when *anything* is sent before you send HTTP headers (with [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) or [`header`](http://php.net/header)). Common reasons for outputting something before the HTTP headers are:

- Accidental whitespace, often at the beginning or end of files, like this:

  ```
     <?php
    // Note the space before "<?php"
    ?>
  ```

To avoid this, simply leave out the closing `?>` - it's not required anyways.

- [Byte order marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of a php file. Examine your php files with a hex editor to find out whether that's the case. They should start with the bytes `3F 3C`. You can safely remove the BOM `EF BB BF` from the start of files.
- Explicit output, such as calls to `echo`, `printf`, `readfile`, `passthru`, code before `<?` etc.
- A warning outputted by php, if the [`display_errors`](http://php.net/display-errors) php.ini property is set. Instead of crashing on a programmer mistake, php silently fixes the error and emits a warning. While you can modify the [`display_errors`](http://php.net/display-errors) or [error_reporting](http://php.net/error-reporting) configurations, you should rather fix the problem.
  Common reasons are accesses to undefined elements of an array (such as `$_POST['input']` without using [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) or [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) to test whether the input is set), or using an undefined constant instead of a string literal (as in `$_POST[input]`, note the missing quotes).

Turning on [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) should make the problem go away; all output after the call to [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start) is buffered in memory until you release the buffer, e.g. with [`ob_end_flush`](http://php.net/ob_end_flush).

However, while output buffering avoids the issues, you should really determine why your application outputs an HTTP body before the HTTP header. That'd be like taking a phone call and discussing your day and the weather before telling the caller that he's got the wrong number.

Answer (score 138):

I got this error many times before, and I am certain all PHP programmer got this error at least once before.

**Possible Solution 1**

This error may have been caused by the blank spaces *before* the start of the file or *after* the end of the file. These blank spaces should not be here.

ex)

```php
<!-- THERE SHOULD BE NO BLANK SPACES HERE -->
<?php  

   echo "your code here";

?>
<!-- THERE SHOULD BE NO BLANK SPACES HERE -->
```

Check all files associated with the file that causes this error.

**Note:** *Sometimes EDITOR(IDE) like `gedit` (a default Linux editor) add one blank line on save file. This should not happen. If you are using Linux. You can use VI editor to remove space/lines after `?>` at the end of the page.*

**Possible Solution 2:**
If this is not your case, then use [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to output buffering:

```php
<?php
  ob_start();

  // code 

 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

This will turn output buffering on and your headers will be created after the page is buffered.

Comment: `ob_start()` just hides the problem; don't use it to solve this particular problem.

Comment: @Ja͢ck If I don't use of `ob_start()`, then what should I do for solving this problem: `Headers already sent`

Comment: @Sajad if you're getting the error specifically because of the editor you're using, you should fiddle with the settings to make it stop causing the problem, or switch editors. If you're getting the error for any other reason, you should read through the replies in this question (specifically the accepted answer) to figure out what the problem actually is, and the solve it.

Comment: `ob_start()` doesn't *"hide"* the problem, it **solves** the problem.

Comment: I had such a problem when I upload my files to server, which supported even PHP5.3 Use server with PHP 5.6 or more

Comment: @jack true, I agree with you. Ideal way is to remove spaces before starting php tag `<?`

Comment: Many people asks where to add `ob_start();`. because after adding the `ob_start();` they still get the error. You have to add to the page that triggered the current page. Ex: page1 (button clicked) -> page2.(header redirect) -> page0 (home). You have to add it to the page1. Many people got confused and add in page2.

Comment: Solved my issue.

Comment: @ManishShrivastava is there any security hack by using ob_start(). Kindly share your experiences.

Answer (score 102):

Instead of the below line

```
//header("Location:".ADMIN_URL."/index.php");
```

write

```
echo "<script>location.href = '".ADMIN_URL."/index.php?msg=$msg';</script>";
```

or

```
?><script><?php echo "location.href = '".ADMIN_URL."/index.php?msg=$msg';";?></script><?php
```

It'll definitely solve your problem.
I faced the same problem but I solved through writing header location in the above way.

Answer (score 56):

This typically occurs when there is unintended output from the script before you start the session. With your current code, you could try to use output buffering to solve it.

try adding a call to the `ob_start();` function at the very top of your script and `ob_end_flush();` at the very end of the document.

Answer (score 44):

You do

```
printf ("Hi %s,</br />", $name);
```

before setting the cookies, which isn't allowed. You can't send any output before the headers, not even a blank line.

Answer (score 43):

## COMMON PROBLEMS:

**1)** there should not be any output (i.e. **`echo..`** or HTML codes) before the **`header(.......);`** command.

**2)** remove any **white-space**(or **newline**) before `<?php` and after `?>` tags.

**3)**  **GOLDEN RULE!** - check if that php file (and also, if you `include` other files) have **UTF8 without BOM** encoding (and not just **UTF-8**). That is problem in many cases (because **UTF8** encoded file has something special character in the start of php file, which your text-editor doesnt show)!!!!!!!!!!!

**4)** After `header(...);` you must use `exit;`

**5)**  always use 301 or 302 reference:

```
header("location: http://example.com",  true,  301 );  exit;
```

**6)** **Turn on error reporting, and find the error.**  Your error may be caused by a function that is not working. When you turn on error reporting, you should always fix top-most error first. For example, it might be "Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings." - then farther on down you may see "headers not sent" error. After fixing top-most (1st) error, re-load your page. If you still have errors, then again fix the top-most error.

**7)** If none of above helps, use JAVSCRIPT redirection(however, strongly non-recommended method), may be the last chance in custom cases...:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location='http://website.com/';</script>"; exit;
```

Comment: Why is explicitly setting `301` or `302` important?

Comment: You can have output if the "output_buffering" in the php.ini file is set. Mine on my home Debian system is set to 4096. The one on the server I am using states that it has no setting.

Answer (score 42):

Lines 45-47:

```
?>

<?php
```

That's sending a couple of newlines as output, so the headers are already dispatched. Just remove those 3 lines (it's all one big PHP block after all, no need to end PHP parsing and then start it again), as well as the similar block on lines 60-62, and it'll work.

Notice that the error message you got actually gives you a lot of information to help you find this yourself:

> Warning: Cannot modify header
>   information - headers already sent by
>   (**output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\speedycms\deleteclient.php:47**)
>   in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\speedycms\deleteclient.php
>   on line 106**

The two bolded sections tell you where the item is that sent output before the headers (line 47) and where the item is that was trying to send a header after output (line 106).

Answer (score 34):

It is because of this line:

```
printf ("Hi %s,</br />", $name);
```

You should not ***print/echo*** anything before sending the headers.

Answer (score 27):

A simple tip: A simple space (or invisible special char) in your script, right before the very first `<?php` tag, can cause this !
Especially when you are working in a team and somebody is using a "weak" IDE or has messed around in the files with strange text editors.

I have seen these things ;)

Answer (score 26):

Check the ***document encoding***.

I had this same problem. I develop on Windows XP using Notepad++ and WampServer to run Apache locally and all was fine. After uploading to hosting provider that uses Apache on Unix I got this error. I had no extra PHP tags or white-space from extra lines after the closing tag.

For me this was caused by the *encoding* of the text documents. I used the "Convert to **UTF-8 without BOM**" option in Notepad++(under *Encoding* tab) and reloaded to the web server. Problem fixed, no code/editing changes required.

Answer (score 23):

Another bad practice can invoke this problem which is not stated yet.

See this code snippet:

```
<?php
include('a_important_file.php'); //really really really bad practise
header("Location:A location");
?>
```

Things are okay,right?

What if "a_important_file.php" is this:

```
<?php
//some php code 
//another line of php code
//no line above is generating any output
?>

 ----------This is the end of the an_important_file-------------------
```

This will not work? Why?Because already a new line is generated.

Now,though this is not a common scenario what if you are using a MVC framework which loads a lots of file before handover things to your controller? This is not an uncommon scenario. Be prepare for this.

From [PSR-2 2.2 :](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

---

- ***All PHP files MUST use the `Unix LF (linefeed) line ending`.***
- ***All PHP files MUST end with a `single blank line`.***
- ***The closing ?> tag MUST be `omitted` from files containing `only php`***

---

Believe me , following thse standards can save you a hell lot of hours from your life :)

Comment: According to several standards (Zend for example), you shouldn't put the closing `?>` tag in any file in any case any way

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Windows environment since it works using any combination (adding closing tags, blanks, pressing enter key, etc). It seems that this issue happens mostly in Linux environments.

Comment: @JuniorM It should be reproducible. Can you share the code you were experimenting in a gist or something alike?

Comment: I am on Windows 7, with latest Wamp installed. I think this bug is related to hidden characters for end of line. My Wordpress' shortcodes.php was the causing the issue. I added to this file a simple function and it started to fire this "headers sent" error. I have compared my shortcodes.php with wordpress' and it was ok, except the `CR LF` (typical Windows end of line). I solve it by downloading the original file from Wordpress repo that has `LF` (Linux end of line) instead of `CR LF` and I also moved my function to theme's functions.php. Based on: http://bit.ly/1Gh6mzN

Comment: @Sahib, notice that still I cannot reproduce what is stated in this answer. The answer is totally fine for Linux environment. I have tested things such a blank between `?>` `<?php`, removing and adding single blank line, added and omitted closing tag `?>`. In Windows+ Wamp all those combinations work fine. Wierd...

Comment: :+1: I had the same problem, but the other way round: The important file, I included had the `header()` command in it and the main script (which had a very similar name) produced output before the include.

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes when the dev process has both WIN work stations and LINUX systems (hosting) and in the code you do not see any output before the related line, it could be the formatting of the file and the lack of *Unix LF (linefeed)* 
 line ending.

What we usually do in order to quickly fix this, is rename the file and on the LINUX system create a new file instead of the renamed one, and then copy the content into that. Many times this solve the issue as some of the files that were created in WIN once moved to the hosting cause this issue.

This fix is an easy fix for sites we manage by FTP and sometimes can save our new team members some time.

Answer (score 10):

There is likely whitespace outside of your php tags.

Answer (score 9):

Those blank lines between your `?>` and `<?php` tags are being sent to the client.

When the first one of those is sent, it causes your headers to be sent first.

Once that happens, you can't modify the headers any more.

Remove those unnecessary tags, have it all in one big `<?php` block.

Answer (score 4):

Generally this error arise when we send header after echoing or printing. If this error arise on a specific page then make sure that page is not echoing anything before calling to `start_session()`.

Example of Unpredictable Error:

```
 <?php //a white-space before <?php also send for output and arise error
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

//your page content
```

One more example:

```
<?php
includes 'functions.php';
?> <!-- This new line will also arise error -->
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

//your page content
```

Conclusion: Do not output any character before calling `session_start()` or `header()` functions not even a white-space or new-line